# Build failure on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: solana-program

Running cargo build on MacBookPro M1 machine for the first time after cloning the solana repository.
Error report:

```
  ld: warning: ignoring file ./.libs/libprotoc.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
  ld: warning: ignoring file ./.libs/libprotobuf.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
  ld: warning: ignoring file ~/solana/target/debug/build/protobuf-src-3957990cd4f40fe4/out/install/build/src/.libs/libprotobuf.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
    "google::protobuf::compiler::objectivec::ObjectiveCGenerator::ObjectiveCGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::objectivec::ObjectiveCGenerator::~ObjectiveCGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator::~CodeGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::js::Generator::~Generator() in main.o
        google::protobuf::compiler::ruby::Generator::~Generator() in main.o
        google::protobuf::compiler::php::Generator::~Generator() in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::AllowPlugins(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::RegisterGenerator(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::Run(int, char const* const*)", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::CommandLineInterface()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface::~CommandLineInterface()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::cpp::CppGenerator::CppGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::cpp::CppGenerator::~CppGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::java::JavaGenerator::JavaGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::java::JavaGenerator::~JavaGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::java::KotlinGenerator::KotlinGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::java::KotlinGenerator::~KotlinGenerator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::Generator::Generator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::csharp::Generator::~Generator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::python::Generator::Generator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "google::protobuf::compiler::python::Generator::~Generator()", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ProtobufMain(int, char**) in main.o
    "vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator::CodeGenerator() in main.o
    NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
    "vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::js::Generator", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::js::Generator::Generator() in main.o
    NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
    "vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::php::Generator", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::php::Generator::Generator() in main.o
    NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
    "vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::ruby::Generator", referenced from:
        google::protobuf::compiler::ruby::Generator::Generator() in main.o
    NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make[1]: *** [protoc] Error 1
  make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  command did not execute successfully, got: exit status: 2

build script failed, must exit now', ~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/autotools-0.2.5/src/lib.rs:715:5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try building from a release tag rather than whatever commit you are here.

Comment: Getting this for v1.14 or v1.16 so this isn't something new with protobuf-src upgrade. Maybe something has changed on macos and it breaks the build.

Comment: tbf, op was from a year ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same exact issue.

I found the "generic" answer here:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20825

In short, i installed binutils at some point, binutils build tool binaries are then used instead of the default ones, and they break the build of protobuf through protobuf-src.

The fix `brew uninstall binutils`, compilation works after that.